# Resize existing images to new style in paperclip & RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

I've been using paperclip to upload and auto-resize photos in my Rails app, and I love it. Only problem is about every other month my crazy manager decides he wants a new size to display the photos in. So I add a new style in my Photo model and all is good for new photos, but the pre-existing photos are now a problem. Now that I'm starting to have more than a few photos to deal with I need a programmatic way to resize existing photos. Perhaps there is some paperclip trick for such a thing? I'd really rather not have to figure out RMagick and write a script myself if I don't have to.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You want the `reprocess!` method of Paperclip::Attachment. See [the docs](http://rdoc.info/projects/thoughtbot/paperclip).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end

# Console...
>> User.find_each { |u| u.avatar.reprocess! }
```

Also, according to the comments before the `reprocess!` method, there's a paperclip:refresh Rake task, which might be easier.

Comment: Here's the documentation to regenerate your paperclip styles. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation The command should be `rake paperclip:refresh:YOUR_STYLE_HERE CLASS=User`

Comment: FYI, if you have a polymorphic model to handle all your Paperclip attachments, called `Picture` for example, you'll need to do something like: `Gallery.pictures.file.reprocess!`.

Comment: This worked for me, whereas the rake task failed (couldn't find the paperclip yml file). I inherited this app, and it doesn't appear to use the yml file.

Answer (score 31):

try this rake task provided by paperclip

```
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles
```

Ref:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#post-processing

Comment: ...or do it for just one model: `rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles CLASS=YourModelName`

Comment: Dont forget to set the rails environment with the task. `rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles CLASS=YourModelName RAILS_ENV=production`