# How do I reprocess images stored by paperclip merely to add an additional style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977234/resize-existing-images-to-new-style-in-paperclip-rmagick).

I have a GalleryPhoto model with ~28,000 records. Each has an image attachment with five styles: original, large, medium, small, and thumb. The large, medium, and small have a watermark applied to them. I want to add an addition style called download to the styles that has no watermark.

How can I reprocess the entire batch to only add the additional style without redoing all of the existing styles? Otherwise the reprocess will probably take days.

```
Rails 3.1.1
Paperclip 2.4.2
ImageMagick 6.2.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did in console, and it seems to be working quite well.

```
GalleryPhoto.order('id DESC').each do |record|
  original_style_name = "original_#{record.image_file_name}"
  new_style_name = "small_download_#{record.image_file_name}"
  image_path = "#{Rails.root}/private/images/galleries/#{record.gallery_id}/#{record.id}"
  system "cd #{image_path} && cp #{original_style_name} #{new_style_name} && mogrify -resize 600x600 #{new_style_name}"
  puts record.id
end
```